# Specific step in the proof of conjugate prior for normal distribution with unknown mean and variance

Tags: bayesian, conjugate-prior

I'm struggling to follow a specific step in the proof that

$$
\tau \sim \text{Gamma}(\alpha, \beta), \quad \mu | \tau \sim \mathcal{N}(\nu, \frac{1}{k\tau})
$$

is a conjugate prior distribution for a sample of iidrvs with distribution 
$\mathcal{N}(\mu, \frac{1}{\tau})$.

I'm able to derive that the posterior distribution is

$$
\pi(\tau, \mu|\mathbf{x}) \propto \tau ^{\alpha + \frac{n}{2} - \frac{1}{2}}\text{exp}\Big(-\tau \Big[\beta + \frac{k}{2}(\mu - \nu)^2 + \frac{1}{2}\sum(x_i-\mu)^2\Big]\Big)
$$

After that, my book (and all other references I could find) just says:

> Complete the square to see that
>   $$
> k(\mu-\nu)^2 + \sum(x_i - \mu)^2
> $$
>   $$=(k + n)\Big(\mu-\frac{k\nu + n\bar{x}}{k + n}\Big)^2 + \frac{nk}{n+k}(\bar{x} - \nu)^2 + \sum(x_i - \bar{x})^2
> $$

I don't see how this follows without doing (what seems like) an unreasonable amount of algebra. I get the sense there must be some neat way of doing this that I'm not spotting.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Several answers already on site demonstrate "completing the square" in respect of similar Bayesian problems. It would be worthwhile taking a look at some of them

Answer (score 0):

$$
\pi(\tau, \mu|\mathbf{x}) \propto \tau ^{\alpha + \frac{n}{2} - \frac{1}{2}}\text{exp}\Big(-\tau \Big[\beta + \frac{k}{2}(\mu - \nu)^2 + \frac{1}{2}\sum(x_i-\mu)^2\Big]\Big)
$$

$$
\pi(\tau, \mu|\mathbf{x}) \propto \tau ^{\alpha + \frac{n}{2} - \frac{1}{2}}\text{exp}\Big(-\tau \Big[\beta + \frac{1}{2}(k + n)\Big(\mu-\frac{k\nu + n\bar{x}}{k + n}\Big)^2 +\frac{1}{2} \frac{nk}{n+k}(\bar{x} - \nu)^2 + \frac{1}{2}\sum(x_i - \bar{x})^2\Big]\Big)
$$

define

$$A=\frac{1}{2} \frac{nk}{n+k}(\bar{x} - \nu)^2 + \frac{1}{2}\sum(x_i - \bar{x})^2$$

$$
\pi(\tau, \mu|\mathbf{x}) \propto \tau ^{\alpha + \frac{n}{2} - \frac{1}{2}}\text{exp}\Big(-\tau \Big[\beta+A + \frac{1}{2}(k + n)\Big(\mu-\frac{k\nu + n\bar{x}}{k + n}\Big)^2 \Big]\Big)
$$

for $\tau$

$$
\pi(\tau|\mathbf{x}) \propto \int \tau ^{\alpha + \frac{n}{2} - \frac{1}{2}}\text{exp}\Big(-\tau \Big[\beta+A + \frac{1}{2}(k + n)\Big(\mu-\frac{k\nu + n\bar{x}}{k + n}\Big)^2 \Big]\Big) d\mu
$$

$$
\pi(\tau|\mathbf{x}) \propto \tau^{\alpha + \frac{n}{2} - \frac{1}{2}}e^{-\tau (\beta+A) }\int
e^{ -\frac{\tau}{2}(k + n)\Big(\mu-\frac{k\nu + n\bar{x}}{k + n}\Big)^2 }
  d\mu
$$

$$
\pi(\tau|\mathbf{x}) \propto \tau^{\alpha + \frac{n}{2} - \frac{1}{2}}e^{-\tau (\beta+A) }\int
e^{ -\frac{\tau}{2}(k + n)\Big(\mu-\frac{k\nu + n\bar{x}}{k + n}\Big)^2 }
  d\mu  \frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{\tau(k + n)}}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{\tau(k + n)}}}
$$

$$
\pi(\tau|\mathbf{x}) \propto \tau^{\alpha + \frac{n}{2} - \frac{1}{2}}e^{-\tau (\beta+A) }
\sqrt{\frac{1}{\tau(k + n)}}\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{\tau(k + n)}}}
e^{ -\frac{\tau}{2}(k + n)\Big(\mu-\frac{k\nu + n\bar{x}}{k + n}\Big)^2 }
  d\mu  
$$

do you see that integral $\propto 1$??(normal distribution).

$$
\pi(\tau, \mu|\mathbf{x}) \propto \tau ^{\alpha + \frac{n}{2} - \frac{1}{2}}\text{exp}\Big(-\tau \Big[\beta + \frac{1}{2}(k + n)\Big(\mu-\frac{k\nu + n\bar{x}}{k + n}\Big)^2 +\frac{1}{2} \frac{nk}{n+k}(\bar{x} - \nu)^2 + \frac{1}{2}\sum(x_i - \bar{x})^2\Big]\Big)
$$

$$
\pi( \mu|\tau,\mathbf{x}) \propto \text{exp}\Big(-\tau \Big[ \frac{1}{2}(k + n)\Big(\mu-\frac{k\nu + n\bar{x}}{k + n}\Big)^2 \Big]\Big)
$$